# Looping through nested lists

Tags: python

I want to loop through each item of a nested list.

```
list = [['1', '1'],['1','1',]]
```

I am trying to loop with a while statement.

Comment: Cool? What is your question? Is there some particular reason you want to use a while-loop over the more idiomatic for-loop?

Comment: You need some thing and you are trying for it , but we don't see any tried code here. show us what you have tried and then we can help you.

Comment: I wanted to loop through each item in a nested list using a while loop.

Comment: It's bad idea to use `list` as variable name

Comment: @Andersson this is just an example, in my actual code there is no variable named list. I do understand that it is bad.

Comment: @poisonishere, you should share your code attempts as well as description of issue and your question

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to do this.

You can use a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (which can be difficult at first to understand for beginners) or just the usual iterative loop:

Let's go for the classical approach:

```
   # I changed the values in the list for the sake of my example here
    lists = [['1', '2'],['3','4',]]

    for sub_list in lists:
      print(sub_list) # e.i ['1','2'] on the first iteration of lists
      for value in sub_list:
        print(value) # 1 on the first iteration of sub_list
```

I'm curious about why you'd want to use a `while` loop to iterate over the list.

** As per @Alexander comment**

`list` is a reserved word so you should avoid using it unless you are actually creating a list from it:

```
my_list = list

my_list() #=> []
```

Comment: `list` is a reserved word.  Don't use it as a variable name.  Also, avoid the use of `l` as a variable (style guidelines).  How about `sub_list`? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id38

Comment: @Alexander, duhhh... thanks! changed that.

Comment: `sub_list` is actually perfectly adequate thank you. Edited.

Comment: @pushpendrachauhan technically, you showed how to use a list-comprehension, which does not do the same thing.

Comment: Also @Alexander what do you think about iterating with a while loop. I find that strange here...

Comment: @Cyzanfar I find the question confusing to begin with as it is not clear what the OP is trying to achieve. I would certainly avoid a `while` loop unless there was a clear reason to use one.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. I'm trying to think of a specific scenario where that would actually be beneficial...